# anytime picker plugin works only on authorized page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i am a bit confuse to why the anytimepicker works perfectly on authorized page but not on publicly viewed page i just copied the code from the authorized page to my publicly viewed page the code is below

```
 <link href="~/Content/anytime.5.0.5.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/anytime.5.0.5.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
               $(".dates").AnyTime_picker({ format: "%Y-%m-%d", hideInput: false });
         });
    </script>
```

and the html inputs where given the class name dates after running the public page the console from google chrome is telling me that there is an error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
i have tried the plugins from bootstrap with the same result i am a bit confuse i had never encountered such error before

any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Are you sure the paths of all the javascript libraries that you're using is correct and valid. If you just copy pasted the code from a website. Then it might not work because, it's all relative paths here.

Comment: yes they are all found inside the script folder and the css on the  content folder i know its the correct path because the page is displaying correctly using bootstrap 3.0

Comment: Is your ready function executing?
Is your selector working, i.e. does $(".dates") return a jQuery object? Do you know how to debug in Chrome?

Comment: yes its all working i just omitted some codes the page displays a map from google and i use ajax to retrieve some latitude and longitude and they are all working except for the plugin from anytimepicker looking at the console all scripts are loaded as expected on the selector yes its all working i have a function on button click which triggers the ajax call

Comment: Check if the 'Anytime' library is loaded correctly. Just try doing `console.log(AnyTime.version)` inside `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: alert(AnyTime.version); it says version 5.0.5

Comment: So if all the javascript libraries are loaded correctly and are working, there might be an issue with your Jquery selector.

Comment: i have a question is there a difference between a 200 and a 304 response when loading java script files?

Comment: got it working after examining the page source i noticed that the shared layout page was injecting the same jquery file on the bottom of the page and after fixing it the calendar appears as expected i didn't know that injecting the same jquery file twice will cause the function to throw an error anyway thank you